# How to sort integer values of NSMutableArray [Objective C]?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sorting, integer, nsmutablearray

I wanted to sort the integer values of my NSMutableArray. I don't know to to do it.

Any help please

Comment: It's not duplicate @kennytm look at the Question. I specified what kind of array. The answer in the Sorting Array in increasing order is not for NSMutableArray its for NSArray.

Comment: Updated duplicate link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *array = /* loaded from file */;

array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[array sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)]];
[array sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)];
```

Comment: I specified  NSMutableArray not NSArray. Sorry

Comment: you can simply convert NSArray and NSMutableArray.

Comment: Hmm. I already solved my issue on my own. by this code [modifiedArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];   .  We'll that's a good answer too. Thanks . Please upvote my question and I will upvote your answer plus I will mark it check @iCoderz

Comment: You can up vote if it is working. @handiansom

Comment: You solution is working the same as mine.